# Change align classes for images

Tags: images, filters

How to change align classes for images in TinyMCE. I can use filters to change the classes for the initial output, but when TinyMCE is used and I update the alignment of the image, the usual "aligncenter", "alignright", etc classes are added to the element. Is there a way to change these?